# C program to set k lower order bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

For a 32 bit integer, how do I set say k low order bits in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something along the lines of

set k lower bits:

```
while (k) {
    k--;
    num |= (1<<k);
}
```

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you want to set the *k* lowest bits of a 32-bit integer *x*, I believe this will work:

```
if( k > 0 ) {
    x |= (0xffffffffu >> (32-k))
}
```

Comment: +1 nice, but I would an unsigned literal `0xffffffffu` just to make sure that the compiler does not try to replicate the sign bit.

Comment: Is it ok if I giggle a little at `0xffffffffu`? :P

Comment: Note that this will fail for `k = 0` (shifting a 32 bit operand by 32 or more bits is undefined behaviour).

Comment: @user not at all. It would OR with 0s, doing nothing to the lower bits. `x |= ~(0xffffffff << k)` would tho'.

Comment: @Graeme: why not check if k is 0?

Comment: @Neil: Because I somehow missed @caf's comment and didn't know about the undefined behaviour. Fixed.

Answer (score 10):

To set `n` least significant bits in `k`, you could use arithmetic:

```
k |= (1 << n) - 1;
```

(Provided `n` is less or equal your int size in bits.)

Comment: That would wipe out the existing bits.

Comment: @Ares: Updated. Use ORing not to wipe out existing bits.

Comment: This fails if `n` is equal to the width of the `int` type.

Comment: @Neil G: Because shifting by an amount equal or greater than the width of the type is undefined behaviour, and in fact this does fail on common platforms.

Comment: @caf: I'm just curious; do you know which platform this fails on?

Comment: @Neil G: x86, for one (where shifting a 32 bit value by 32 will leave the number unchanged).

Comment: `k |= (int)((1ull << n) - 1)` should work in this borderline case, doesn't it?

Comment: The `1ull` only works if `n` is less than the width of `unsigned long long` (at least 64).  This question assumes `n <= 32`, so yes that works.  `~(UINTMAX_MAX << (n - 1))` works no matter how big `n` is.  That `(int)` cast is unnecessary and possibly even unsafe.  If you are going to be twiddling individual bits, you should be using unsigned types to get predictable behavior.  The bit representation of signed types is implementation defined.  Although you won't find many systems that aren't 2's-complement today, it's still best to use an unsigned type for `k` (so `unsigned`, not `int`).

Answer (score 1):

```
int bitmask = 1;
for (ix = 0;  ix < k;  ++ix)
{
    C = C | bitmask;
    bitmask <<= 1;
}
```